# Number formatting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to ruby and rails, I wanted to have an attribute in a database which is a number

->The number can have a maximum length of 10.
->The number is separated into 3 parts, each part being delimited by a "-".
->The first part from the left can have 2-7 digits, the second part should have exactly 2 digits
and the third part should have exactly 1 digit.

for example
23-56-7
3454-54-3
3435464-54-3  are valid numbers,
How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends , it's not a number if it contains '-' so you'll probably want to store it as a string and validate it at creation .

There are 2 ways you can do that , from the database or from rails .
I'll suggest validating it from rails model .
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

You'll probably want to user a regex for the validations .
http://www.rubular.com

And if you want to perform calculations on the numbers you can easily do something like this

```
yournumber.split('-').map { |x| x.to_i }
```

this will return an array with 3 integers .

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set a string datatype and you can make validation using appropriate regular expression using http://www.rubular.com/ 
for example : 23-56-7

```
validates_format_of     :number, :with => /^[1-9][1-9]-[1-9][1-9]-[1-9]$/
```

Comment: Your regex fails on some rules. A better one is: `\d{2,7}-\d{2}-\d`